# Function template overload with std::function type parameter, nullptr value and shared_ptr type

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, std-function, overload-resolution

In the example below, why does the last one calls the function overload with std::function as parameter?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template <class Type>
void make_something(Type&& a){
    std::cout<<"Type&& overload"<<std::endl;
}

template <class Type>
void make_something(std::function<Type()>){
    std::cout<<"std::function overload"<<std::endl;
}


int main(){ 
    make_something<int>(1);  // prints "Type&& overload"
    make_something<int>(nullptr);  // prints "std::function overload"
    make_something<int*>(nullptr);  // prints "Type&& overload"

    using ptr_int = std::shared_ptr<int>;
    make_something<ptr_int>(nullptr);  // prints "std::function overload" ... why?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion from `std::nullptr_t` to both `std::shared_ptr<int>` and `std::function<std::shared_ptr<int>()>`.

This means that calling `make_something<ptr_int>(nullptr)` needs to do the same amount of conversions to transform the `std::nullptr_t` argument into the function argument (a user-defined conversion sequence).

If these were both non-template functions, this would be ambiguous. Since they are templates, the tiebreakers for templates can be used.

`std::function<Type()>` is more specialised than `Type` (cv- and ref- qualifications are discarded for this check). This means that `std::function<Type()>` overload is chosen.

If you were to add a third more specialized overload, that would be chosen:

```cpp
template <class Type>
void make_something(std::function<Type*()>){
    std::cout<<"std::function Type* overload"<<std::endl;
}
```

This is generally used when the type is deduced (e.g., if you called `make_something(std::function<int()>{})`, it would be ambiguous without the template rules), but has this unexpected behaviour when you specify the template argument.